# If $B(q)$ is a symmetric matrix and $B(0)$ is positive definite, is $T = p^T B(q) p$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, stability-theory

In book "Stability Theory by Lyapunov's Direct Method" by Laloy there is a General Hypotheses concerning stability, which says:

"The kinetic energy is $T(q, p) = \frac{1}{2} p^TB(q)p$, where $B(q)$ is symmetric and $C^1$, and $B(0)$ is positive definite. [...]"

If $B(0)$ is positive definite, then $p^TB(0)p$ is bigger than or equal zero for any p, but does it also means that $p^TB(q)p$ is bigger than or equal zero for any p?

If $B(0)$ is positive definite, is $B(q)$ positive definite?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: you should identify the book or link to which you refer. Then typeset the ODE system you are discussing.  Then tell us how your $B$ appears for that system

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, concerning B, there are no other informations in the book, except that this is a conservative mechanical system

Comment: what page?  there are a few pages of preview available online

Comment: page 99, in the beginning of section 2 "The Lagrangian Dirichlet Theorem and Its Variants", from chapter 3 "Stability of a Mechanical Equilibrium"

Comment: it won't show page 99. Alright, look at that page and the pages just before it and find out what system is being discussed. As @Ben  has indicated, nothing can be done without knowing a definition for your $B$

Comment: unfortunately there is no more information about matrix B, but as it is a mechanical system it would be analogous to "mass", but thanks for the recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless we have more information about $B(q)$, the answer is no. For instance, consider
$$
B(q) = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 1 - q}
$$
and consider the vector $p = (0,1)^T$.